# Python Pandas Dataframe replace values below treshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I apply a function element-wise to a pandas DataFrame and pass a column-wise calculated value (e.g. quantile of column)? For example, what if I want to replace all elements in a DataFrame (with `NaN`) where the value is lower than the 80th percentile of the column?

```
def _deletevalues(x, quantile):
if x < quantile:
    return np.nan
else:
    return x

df.applymap(lambda x: _deletevalues(x, x.quantile(0.8)))
```

Using `applymap` only allows one to access each value individually and throws (of course) an `AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'quantile'`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: replace `x.quantile` by `df.quantile`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [139]: df
Out[139]:
   a  b  c
0  1  7  3
1  1  2  6
2  3  0  5
3  8  2  1
4  7  3  5
5  6  7  2
6  0  2  1
7  8  4  1
8  5  0  6
9  7  7  6
```

for **all** columns:

```
In [145]: df.apply(lambda x: np.where(x < x.quantile(),np.nan,x))
Out[145]:
     a    b    c
0  NaN  7.0  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  6.0
2  NaN  NaN  5.0
3  8.0  NaN  NaN
4  7.0  3.0  5.0
5  6.0  7.0  NaN
6  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  8.0  4.0  NaN
8  NaN  NaN  6.0
9  7.0  7.0  6.0
```

or

```
In [149]: df[df < df.quantile()] = np.nan

In [150]: df
Out[150]:
     a    b    c
0  NaN  7.0  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  6.0
2  NaN  NaN  5.0
3  8.0  NaN  NaN
4  7.0  3.0  5.0
5  6.0  7.0  NaN
6  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  8.0  4.0  NaN
8  NaN  NaN  6.0
9  7.0  7.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 18):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.mask(df < df.quantile())
print (df)
     a    b    c
0  NaN  7.0  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  6.0
2  NaN  NaN  5.0
3  8.0  NaN  NaN
4  7.0  3.0  5.0
5  6.0  7.0  NaN
6  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  8.0  4.0  NaN
8  NaN  NaN  6.0
9  7.0  7.0  6.0
```